# How to check Table depended view's procedure

Tags: mysql

i have table student,fields are student_id, student_name, year_joining ...

now i want to rename the year_joining to year_completion ,

but i am not sure, How many view,procedure functions depend this year_joinging ,

In mysql, is there any function do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try querying the `information_schema` database:

```
USE `information_schema`;
SELECT * FROM `VIEWS` WHERE `VIEW_DEFINITION` LIKE '%year_joining%';
SELECT * FROM `ROUTINES` WHERE `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` LIKE '%year_joining%';
```

This should return a list of views/routines which reference the field `year_joining`.

I think I'm right in saying that, in either case, the column `TABLE_NAME` will contain the name of the view/procedure, and the column `VIEW_DEFINITION` or `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` will contain the definition of the view/procedure.

To restrict the search to a particular database, include `TABLE_SCHEMA` or `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` in your query, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM `VIEWS` WHERE `VIEW_DEFINITION` LIKE '%year_joining%' AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'my_database';
SELECT * FROM `ROUTINES` WHERE `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` LIKE '%year_joining%' AND `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` = 'my_database';
```